# Will ipod 2nd generation support newer ios

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

Will 2nd generation mod MB533C support newer ios ?
I have a much older ipod touch and would like to use imessage. Is this model capable of doing so?

Comment: Have you tried checking Apple Support (support.apple.com)?

Comment: According to the thread at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6975805?language=en, Gen 2 iPod Touches should be compatible to iOS 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

As Arc676 comments:

### A Generation 2 iPod Touch's latest possible firmware is iOS 4.2.1, which **does not** support iMessage.